# Why my offset variable's value remains zero

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to make a simple Tumblr scraper using node.js

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var apiKey = 'my-key-here';
var offset = 0;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  console.log('request #' + i + '...');

  var requestURL = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key='
    + apiKey
    + '&offset='
    + offset;

  console.log(requestURL);

  request(requestURL, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var resultAsJSON = JSON.parse(body);
      resultAsJSON.response.posts.forEach(function(obj) {
        fs.appendFile('content.txt', offset + ' ' + obj.title + '\n', function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
        });   
        offset++;  
      });       
    }
  }); 
}
```

By default, the API only returns a maximum of 20 latest posts. I want to grab all the posts instead. As a test, I want to get the latest 100 first, hence the `i<5`in the loop declaration.

The trick to do it is to use the `offset` parameter. Given an `offset` value of 20, for example, the API will not return the latest 20, but instead returns posts starting from the 21st from the top.

As I can't be sure that the API will always return 20 posts, I am using `offset++` to get the correct offset number.

The code above works, but `console.log(requestURL)` returns `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=my-key-here&offset=0`
 five times.

So my question is, why does the `offset` value in my `requestURL` remains as 0, even though I have added `offset++`?

Comment: Not this again. You fire off a request and expect it to complete before the loop goes to the next iteration. The requests doesn't even get started until after the loop completes which is why `offset` is zero for all of them. You need an asynchronous for-each loop.

Comment: The thing is I'm writing the `offset` variable in `appendFile`, and they showed up correctly in the text file from 0 to 99.

Comment: That's just due to the callbacks to the requests occurring in the same sequence they were fired in but that is not guaranteed and you should not depend on it.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I thought this is some sort of variable scoping gotcha that I'm unaware of, but now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increment the `offset` in the loop, not in callbacks. Callbacks fire only after the request has been completed, which means you make five requests with `offset = 0` and it's incremented after you get a response.

```
  var requestURL = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key='
    + apiKey
    + '&offset='
    + (offset++); // increment here, before passing URL to request();
```

Edit: 
To offset by 20 in each iteration, and use the offset in callback:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
var offset = i * 20, requestURL = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key='
    + apiKey
    + '&offset='
    + offset;

    (function(off){ 
        request(requestURL, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var resultAsJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                resultAsJSON.response.posts.forEach(function(obj) {
                    fs.appendFile('content.txt', off + ' ' + obj.title + '\n', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });   
                    off++;  
                });       
            }
        });
    }(offset)); // pass the offset from loop to a closure
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between `i` and `offset`, though. `offset` needs to be the number of posts to be skipped, while `i` is the number of times I want to use the API. 1 API call gives up to 20 posts at once.

Comment: But in your question you increment offset by one in each iteration, so I've assumed `offset == i`. Use `offset = i * 20` then.

Comment: `offset++` is inside the `forEach` scope, which iterates all of the posts returned by the API. So I'm counting the posts there.

Comment: Tried running it. Got an error: `}(offset)); // pass the offset from loop to a closure SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: forgot `);` in the line before `}(offset));`